# Road bike shifter cable breaks too often: Shimano ultegra 10

Tags: shimano, shifter, cable, failure

My rear derailleur shifter cable just broke for the *third time* in two years 5000 miles/ 8000km. I was lucky this time. It broke a mile from the end of a long ride.

What am I doing wrong? Are there cables that don't break as easily? Or do I just have to replace those cables every 1000 miles?

**Edit** It breaks inside the shifter, right where it's the biggest possible pain in the xxx neck to get the broken mushroom head out.

The design is pretty bad.  The very end of the cable wraps around a small-radius capstan, and gets bent when downshifting and straightened when upshifting. My high school physics teacher showed his class how to do that repeatedly to induce metal fatigue and break an otherwise strong stainless steel cable.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not using cheap junk cables here but your experience is not normal.  I've never ever broken a shifter cable.  Perhaps there is a problem with the cable routing or your rear mech.  Perhaps a photo or two of the setup would help.

Comment: I'm guessing the cable is rubbing against something.

Comment: Can you measure how far from the mushroom head the cable broke?  IE, did it fracture inside the shifter, or somewhere else on the run?

Comment: When you fit a new cable, is it easy to shift at first and then gets progressively harder over the weeks and months?

Comment: Do you chage the outers at the same time or are they original ?

Comment: Where is the cable breaking?  If it's inside the shifter body its a known issue with shimano 10 speed sti levers.  Typically in my family bikes get serviced every year which includes new cables, but if they get forgotten and it stretches to more like 18 months a broken cable acts as a reminder.

Comment: It’s pretty common for the cable to break inside the shifter. Usually you get early warning because shifting to the smallest sprockets no longer works. Low friction and good cables help.

Comment: @Michael Really to to smallest and not to the largest sprockets?

Comment: @VladimirF: Yes. The cable frays inside the shifter and then the derailleur is unable to pull in cable when shifting to smaller sprockets.

Comment: @Michael OK, the problem is probably in my head wrongly imagining which direction is pulling and which releasing. I have a very similar problem on my gravel bike and it does not shift to the large chainring. I did not disassemble it yet, but I was quite convinced it is this problem when I left it.

Comment: @AndyP FWIW, Shimano's 11-speed shifters have the same "feature".

Comment: It is probably not about the number of speeds but about the inner cable routing (now present in all levels from 8-speed to 11-speed).

Comment: @Michael My problem was different and that explains my why my shifting problems were different. My cable was almost completely broken in the clamp on the front derailleur.